# Make -j works but -jN is not working

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

My Makefile looks as follows:

```
test:
    make clean
    make test2
test2: CXX=g++
test2: all

CPP_FILES := $(wildcard tmp/*.cpp)
OBJ := $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)

all: ${OBJ}
    ${CXX} ${OBJ} ${LIB_PATH} ${LIBS} ${CXX_FLAGS} -o output.exe

%.o: %.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CXX_FLAGS} ${INCLUDE_PATH} -c $< -o $@
```

All the .o files can (and should) be build in parallel. This is working if I execute "make -j" but it fails if I limit the number of processes to some fixed number (say 4) via "make -j4". This will result in the following message:

```
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.
```

Can someone please point me to my mistake? Why is "make -j" working while "make -j4" gives this error message?

Thanks!

Comment: What `make` are you using? There's different implementations with different capabilities. Also, you say you're running this with `-j4` but the error message says something about `-j1`.

Comment: Never call make from make, use `$(MAKE)` or some other magic string like that.

Comment: The "magic strings" are exactly `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}` (they're exactly equivalent).  Or you can prefix the recipe with the `+` character.  Info here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html  However you should always use `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}` for other reasons as well.

Comment: @cubic: I am using -j4. The error message is merely saying that '-j1' will be used instead of '-j4'

Comment: @marc: thank you. this solved my problem. Feel free to create an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion) for recursive calls in GNU make. Essentially, you need to call `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}` instead of plain `make` or at least prefix the line in the recipe with `+` so that the sub-make can properly communicate with the parent make. This is particularly useful when you ask for job control.