# command 'make -jN' is not working after 'make clean'

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

So, whenever i compile my project using `make` command at my SDK, i have question.

i know how `-j` option works but i still have no idea there is a compile error after `make clean`, then `make -j10`

Solution for this is, after `make clean`, i should compile with `make -j1`.
After compile is completed with `-j1`, `make` with `-j100`, `-j200` works fine.

Any ideas?

[Make -j works but -jN is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975525/make-j-works-but-jn-is-not-working)
this is not the answer that i am looking for

Comment: There's no possible way we can help with the limited amount of information provided.  For example, "there is a compile error" is not useful.  What is the error?  Does your build do anything "unusual" like generate header files or other files needed for compilation?  When a `make -j` fails but `make -j1` succeeds it means that your makefile is missing some prerequisite statements, such that targets that actually have a dependency relationship are not known to make, so it can't ensure they are built in the correct order.  But there's nothing we can say without knowing more.

Comment: i was thinking about a dependency relationship for that.
reason for saying only "compile error" is... because errors are different all the time.
error prints with the line number and "variable" is not defined. hope this can at least help to answer this question.

Comment: Not really.  The first thing to be sure of is you're looking at the _first_ error generated, not the last one.  When dealing with compile failures always start with the first one, since subsequent errors might be a result of the first problem.  If you get an error that a variable is not defined, you need to look at the source file where the error happened.  Where is that variable supposed to be defined?  It must be in some kind of generated file, if it works with `make -j1`.  Then make sure that file is a prerequisite of the file where you got the error.